# Powershell Script to Automate Mailbox to PST

Tags: powershell

I have one script which is working though but I am not a advanced programmer. Please somebody modify my script as I wanted to ?

1) Mailboxes should be exported from specific server "ServerX". Right now this script scans all exchange databases.

2) Just to verify when ever I run this script it should exactly take preceding month backup to desired shared location. Say If run this script on Dec 9 2015, it supposed take backup from Nov. 9 to Dec. 9 2015.

3)Lower part of script never worked where it checks the export request. Can somebody suggest what kind of modification it needs.

```
$Export = Get-Mailbox
$endDate = Get-Date "00:00:00"
$startDate = $endDate.AddDays(-30)

$month = "{0:D2}" -f [int]$startDate.Month
$year = "{0:D4}" -f [int]$startDate.Year

Write-Host -NoNewline "Exporting items between $startDate and $endDate..."

$Export|%{$_|New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $startDate) -and (Received -lt $endDate)} -FilePath "\\FileServer\EmailBackups\ExportTest\Test\$($_.alias).pst"}

Write-Host "Done."

**After this script gives error. But mailboxes exported successfully.**

Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting for export to complete..."
While(!(Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Exprot -Status Completed))
{
    #Sleep for a  few minutes
    Write-Host -NoNewline "."
    Start-Sleep -s 60
}
Write-Host "Done."

Write-Host -NoNewline "Removing Export Request..."
Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Export -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxExportRequest
Write-Host "Done."
```

Comment: `while(!(Get-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $Exprot` has a spelling mistake - it should say `$Export`.